# Configure raid for IBM x3200 M2

Tags: hardware-raid, raid1, hardware

I have a x3200 server and I have planing to use raid 1 for mirroring Sata Hardisk .
I am searching on google to find  raid server manager for x3200 , but no luck .
Is there another way to configure raid in those server ? 
I am using 2 SATA hd 500 Gb , and planing using SLES 11 OS .
Please give me a link or guidence to implement raid.

I realy appriciate for any help and sugestion.

Answer (score 1):

Use the built in LSI Configuration Program to configure RAID on your x3200

To access that utility, Turn on your server, wait untili you get the message <<< Press  to start LSI Configuration Utility>>> displayed, then press Ctrl+C

Comment: Hello , I can not found the message " Press to start LSI config .. "

Answer (score 0):

This is Old question. Hope some one will benifit from this. The IBM's have [SAS2IRCU](https://datacentersupport.lenovo.com/in/en/products/SERVERS/SYSTEM-X/SYSTEM-X3200-M2/downloads/DS117061) (Command Line) Utility for Storage Management to achieve the Raid Configuration.
Documentation for the above tool [here](https://docs.broadcom.com/docs/12353380)